# Get Autocomplete for a special variable in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using vs code for python scripts. These scripts run on the server only.
The server however, passes certain variables to the script while executing the script.

e.g `mbo` is always passed in it. `mbo` is special keyword which corresponds to a some class.
Sample `mbo.py`

```
class Mbo:
    def getString(column: str)-> str:
        return 'ABC'
    def setString(columnName: str)-> None:
        # do something with columnName.
```

**Goal:**
In my project in any python file whenever the user types `mbo` followed by a **.** vs code should show autoscomplete for `.getString()` and `.setString()` without importing this class as it is passed to the script by server.

I can try to write an extension for vs code to add this feature.

Here, I am stuck that what kind of extension is needed here. A LSP? I don't want to loose the feature of the existing python LSP for python.

Can any one proficient with vs code extension API guide me in right direction.

**Note:** I cannot import this Mbo class just for autocompletion in vscode because I import it. Then I run the same script on server. The server throws errors about the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making the imports conditional:

```py
try:
    mbo
except NameError:
    import mbo
```

That might be enough to make one of the two IntelliSense engines in the Python extension work.

Otherwise you are looking at your own extension. LSP is obviously the best option but there's also the classic style of registering classes. The [VS Code docs have the details](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-code-completion-proposals). But you are still probably going to clash with the Python extension as both it and your extension will be registered to work with Python files.

Comment: This is what I am already doing. This works but the problem with this is mbo is not the only variable. There are about 29 variables in total. Writing try for them in each script will cause the code to be unnecessary long.